# Copying a specific column and line from a text file: BATCH

Tags: batch-file, find

I have the following text file from a find command

```
---------- TEXT.TXT
[7]test
```

I would like to copy the 7 from in this text file using columns and lines. I was thinking I could do something like this.

```
set /p line=text.txt cols=2 lines=2
```

This clearly does not work.

Comment: You should consider changing the way you are using the find command to get cleaner output without the file name it matched on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 delims=[] tokens=1-3" %%A in (testing.txt) do (
set line=%%A 
goto :next
)

:next
pause
```

- The `for` loops search for the 2nd line of `tesing.txt`
- Gets the string between `[` and `]`
- Sets `line` to the string.

If there is space between the `[` and `]`, add quotes to the file like so:

```
["7 8"]
```

Comment: That was a bug in my old script, have you tried my updated script?